# Why am I getting the error "scons: *** no platform named 'win32'"?

Tags: windows, scons

I was trying to compile some C++ source that uses scons as its build system. On my 64 bit windows machine with python 3.2.X (64 bit) and what I thought was python 2.7.X (32 bit) I would get the following error when trying to run scons:

> scons: *** no platform named 'win32'

I was fairly certain that my 2.7 installation was 32 bit, because in the past I'd tried using scons with a 64 bit system and it had outright refused to function. I spent an hour or so playing with it, tried repairing the install, poking around on google/SO, etc. but couldn't find a solution. Finally I uninstalled python 2.7 using both a 32 and a 64 bit installer (I guess I must've had both installed in the same location?), uninstalled scons, deleted the remaining python27 folder and reinstalled 32 bit python and scons.

Now scons works!

Since I hadn't found a solution on SO, I thought I should post mine, but I'd also like to know what causes this error?

What causes the scons error "no platform named 'win32'"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have actually had this problem myself. This is caused by the *scons.bat* using the wrong python library. Somehow the installation gets screwed up and when you run things in 2.7 it tries using the libraries from python 3. I solved this quite simply by editing the *scons.bat* script, and setting  python path and python home in the script.

The changes are shown here.

```
Set PYTHONHOME=C:\Python27\
Set PYTHONPATH=C:\Python27\Lib\;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
Set PATH=%PYTHONHOME%;%PYTHONPATH%;%PATH%

...
more stuff here
...
:WinNT
setlocal
@REM ensure the script will be executed with the Python it was installed for
set path=%~dp0;%~dp0..;%path%
c:\Python27\python -c "from os.path import join; import sys; sys.path = [ join  (sys.prefix, 'Lib', 'site-packages', 'scons-2.0.1'), join(sys.prefix, 'Lib', 'site-    packages', 'scons'), join(sys.prefix, 'scons-2.0.1'), join(sys.prefix, 'scons')] +   sys.path; import SCons.Script; SCons.Script.main()" %*
endlocal & set SCONS_ERRORLEVEL=%ERRORLEVEL%
```

After this it works fine as long as I specify this scons.bat script for running scons.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!

I had almost given up on getting this answered.

Comment: I wish someone had answered the question while I was struggling, now hopefully my experience will help someone else.

Comment: Yeah, and I think your solution is probably better than the "uninstall, reinstall" that I did.